# Show active or warning in the table view with foreach

Tags: c#, razor, foreach

That's the way I want to see if it's active one's membership or not. I have described my colors in my controller that appear on my view page.

Right now, it's just saying class and then there will be nothing after that, for example, be active or warning color.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.GetmembersList)
{
<tr class="@if (item.DenouncedUser == false){ Html.Raw(Model.Coloractive);  }else if(item.DenouncedUser == true){ Html.Raw(Model.Colorwarning); }">
    <th scope="row">
     <a href="/AdminMembers/Users/@item.MembersShipValueId" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">See more</a>
     </th>
   <td>
</tr>
}
```

error are:

```
<tr class>
```

i need to

```
<tr class"active">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it the following way using [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) which quite short and readable too in razor code:

```
<tr class="@(@item.DenouncedUser ? Model.Colorwarning : Model.Coloractive)">
```